# GetAppServiceIdentityAsync AAD returns null

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services

I have a working Azure Mobile .NET backend which has a requirement to expose data securely through a TableController.

The table controller has the the [Authorize] attribute on the controller class definition and I have Token Store Enabled in the Azure Portal's Authentication / Authorization blade.

I'm using the following code to get the user's credentials passed by the mobile client app:

var creds = await this.User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync(this.Request);

However, when deployed to the Azure portal this always returns a NULL exception; digging deeper I can see "Exception=System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The 'principal' parameter must be of type 'ClaimsPrincipal'."

Using JWT.IO, I've inspected the token being passed from the client app and the token looks 100% correct.

With the backend deployed to the Azure Portal and a breakpoint set I see that this.User is null!

How do I get access to the user's credentials, has anyone got this working?

Cheers,
Iain

Comment: Not able to reproduce this issue, can you able to reproduce this issue to deploy it a new mobile app and using the template back-end code by download from Azure portal?

Comment: Fei - cheers, I will give this a try.

Comment: Finally, I've got a working solution, but not using User.GetAppServiceIndentityAsync as User is always null.  Will post code later.